# How to mount docker volume in Azure Web App for containers?

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-storage, krakend

I'm trying to run KrakenD image in Azure App Service.

KrakenD requires json config file krakend.json to be put into /etc/krakend/ (*KrakenD image is based on Linux Alpine*)

I created Web App for containers with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  krakend:
    image: devopsfaith/krakend:latest
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/krakend:/etc/krakend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

Added storage account with a blob container where uploaded sample kraken.json file
[image]

In app configuration i added a path mapping like this:

[image]

But it looks like volume was not mounted correctly

> 2019-11-15 12:46:29.368 ERROR - Container create failed for
>   krakend_krakend_0_3032a936 with System.AggregateException,  One or
>   more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status
>   code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume
>   specification: ':/etc/krakend'"} ) (Docker API responded with status
>   code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume
>   specification: ':/etc/krakend'"} ) InnerException:
>   Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status
>   code=InternalServerError,  response={"message":"invalid volume
>   specification: ':/etc/krakend'"}
>
> 2019-11-15 12:46:29.369 ERROR - multi-container unit was not started
>   successfully

Additional questions

1. What does mean **Mount path** in Storage mounting? - i put there value */krankend*
2. volume definition starts with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} [in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app#modify-configuration-file) they specified it as

   volumes:
         - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html

so i did it by analogy and tried all 3 possible paths

```
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/krakend
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/krakend
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/krakend
```

but no luck  - still getting the error

> ERROR parsing the configuration file: '/etc/krakend/krakend.json'
>   (open): no such file or directory

Answer (score 9):

finally resolved that with the following docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  krakend:
    image: devopsfaith/krakend:latest
    volumes:
      - volume1:/etc/krakend
    environment:
     WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE: TRUE
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

where volume1 is a blob storage mounted as the following

[image]

Comment: I had a same issue working to set up envoy proxy on Azure App Service using docker compaose, this helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: still in preview

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me. I was getting `Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.`

This worked. docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  backend:
    image: xxxx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - vol1:/var/www/html/public

volumes: 
   vol1:
      driver: local
```

Volume definition:

- Name: vol1
- Config: basic
- Storage accounts: ...
- Storage container: ...
- Mount paht: /var/www/html/public