# Mount azure storage account in docker-compose

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-storage, azure-files

How can I Mount azure storage account as a volume in the docker-compose?

I checked this driver but it's deprecated and the [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/) provided there, & it is inactive.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    image: web:74
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the url of the blob path,

```
volumes:
  - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/zoo1/data:/data
```

here is an [`example`](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-box-premium-dist/blob/da8c8f8c1875dd84d740a8279cc92272b6133241/docker-compose-azure.yml)

Comment: what's the value of `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME`?

Comment: That is just an environment variable. you can hardcode

Comment: ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} is an environment variable in App Service that is mapped to persistent storage for your app. You don't have to define anything.

Comment: But in dev environment, I need the container running on my local machine to fetch the data from Azure storage.

Comment: check this too, this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878134/how-to-mount-docker-volume-in-azure-web-app-for-containers